# Android MediaPlayer isn't playing sounds, but it isn't throwing any errors

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I've looked at all of the proposed answers to variants of this question, but none of them have  helped. My app is supposed to teach Morse Code. The only part not working is the Player.java file, which is supposed to take a morse "letter" object, read its code, and play a sequence of tones(which are stored in the res.raw folder as .mp3s). The pertinent bit of this code is the playSound(int pfile, Context pcontext) function. Here it is:

```
package com.ewg.morseCode;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.ewg.morseCode.morse_alphabet.letter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Player extends Activity{
public static boolean finished = false;
public static class player{
    public int dit;
    public int dah;
    public player(){
        this.dit = R.raw.morse_dit;
        this.dah = R.raw.morse_dah;
    }
    //////PERTINENT BIT//////
    private void playSound(int pfile, Context pcontext){

        final int file = pfile;
        final Context context = pcontext;
        MediaPlayer mp =MediaPlayer.create(context, file);
        mp.start();
        while(mp.isPlaying()){

        }
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
    //////END PERTINENT BIT//////
    public void pause(int dur){
        finished = false;
        CountDownTimer timer1 = new CountDownTimer(dur, dur){
            public void onTick(long blah){

            }
            public void onFinish(){
                finished = true;
            }
    }.start();
    while(finished = false){

    }
    }
    public void play(letter x, Context context) throws Exception{

        Exception e = new Exception();
        for(int i = 0; i< x.code.length-1; i++){
            switch(x.code[i]){
            case 0:
                playSound(dit, context);
                pause(49);
                break;
            case 1:
                playSound(dah, context);
                pause(49);
                break;
            default:
                throw(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for any bad coding, I'm still just a scriptkiddie.

*EDIT This is the code that calls the player class, @Geobits*

```
    player player = new player();
    letter Letter = morse_alphabet.hardLetters.get(0);//Letter has a String name property of "b" and a int[] code property of {1, 0, 0, 0}
    try {
    player.play(Letter, context);//context =main_activity.this
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please don't beg or tell us how URGENT your question is; it's no more urgent here than everyone else's is to them. If your question is that URGENT, hire someone to immediately drop everything else and solve your problem. And while we're on the subject, it's not necessary to SHOUT here. We're all quite good at reading, and you don't need to YELL to get our attention. It's annoying and quite rude, and does nothing but make your question harder to read. They invented the Shift key because proper case makes text more readable; making your question harder to read makes answers slower to get.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not trying to yell, I'm just in over my head and scared that I'll fail high school(because this is my senior project and it's due on January 8th). I can't hire anybody, because I'm dirt poor and currently homeless. I'm sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your playSound function like this and don't forget turn on the volume

```
private void playSound(int pfile, Context pcontext){

    final int file = pfile;
    final Context context = pcontext;
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, file);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the volume at max, on my AVD and on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use an `OnCompletionListener` instead of an empty while loop. It may not fix your problem, but it won't hurt for sure, and is the more proper way of doing it.

```
//////PERTINENT BIT//////
private void playSound(int pfile, Context pcontext)
{

    final int file = pfile;
    final Context context = pcontext;
    MediaPlayer mp =MediaPlayer.create(context, file);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
{
    mp.release();
}

//////END PERTINENT BIT//////
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed your suggestion, and although it didn't fix the problem I'm grateful for the advice.

Comment: On second look, is there any reason for wrapping the `player` class in another `Player` class extending from `Activity`? Is there more code to `Player` you cropped, or is this it? If that's it, then I don't see any reason to use an `Activity` class here, and no reason to have `player` as an inner class. Either way, it may help to see the code that actually calls `play()`

Comment: I did it this way to help myself, because I have trouble with organization. This is in a separate .java file from the main_activity.java file. The code that calls play is as follows: 


    player player = new player();


    letter Letter = morse_alphabet.hardLetters.get(0);


    try {


 player.play(morse_alphabet.hardLetters.get(2), context);


  } catch (Exception e) {


   // TODO Auto-generated catch block


   e.printStackTrace();


  }


//Letter has a String name property of "b" and a int[] code property of {1, 0, 0, 0}


//context = main_activity.this

Comment: Sorry for the horrible formatting in that strip of code, I'll post it as an edit to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would second all the suggestions that you should use OnCompletionListener to release your player or at least do this in your activity onPause.

It happened with me once that my program started few players and did not release (leaked), so when I tried to run again it was not able to create new player. I am not sure if it is the same for you, but a phone **restart** solved my problem and my code worked without any changes (I tried to kill my app and other services but it did not help).

Important side comments:

- You do not need to create an exception object in advance, since it is a waste of memory. Just create the exception object when you are throwing the exception.

e.g.

```
 throw(new Exception("Unsupported command")); // Also you should provide a descriptive message
```

Also there is a bug in your code

```
 while(finished = false) // it should be ==
```

or better you should use

```
 while(!finished)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug, I make a lot of careless mistakes like that. I'm not too good at debugging my own code yet. As for restarting the phone, I'm not using an actual device, because I can't afford one. I'm using an AVD, running Android 2.2 and with sound playback enabled. The volume on both my computer and the AVD are both at max.

Comment: I would suggest to start by running the ApiDemos from Android SDK samples, and see if the audio sample will work; to make sure that your AVD is configured properly. Then try your code after correcting it with the suggested modifications

Comment: I checked it, and the AVD is working fine. I tried all of the suggestions; still no go. I'm going to try it with .wav and .ogg files, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

a bad solution,... but useful solution

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, file);
//write these after
mp.start();
mp.pause();
```